# Unable to group data properly

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
emp id    Teamid   emp_add   emp_type
112        1000         mum       Sup
153        1000         del       int
146        1000         lon       man
124        1000         kar       lead
```

I want to group the table in this way:

```
Super_id   EMP_ID  Team_id  emp_add  emp_type 
112         146     1000     lon       man
112         153     1000     del       int
112         124     1000     kar       lead
```

I have written the following code:

```
select case when emp_type = 'sup' then emp_id else null as Super_id,
       case when emp_type <> 'sup' then emp_id,
teamid, emp_add, emp_type

from table
group by team_id, emp_type, emp_add;
```

I am getting the following output:

```
super_id   emp_id   team_id   emp_add   emp_type
null        146        1000    lon        man
null        153        1000    del        int
null        124        1000    kar        lead
```

Can someone suggest the correct code

Comment: What exactly sql are you using and why do you need grouping here by `emp_type, emp_add`?

Comment: is this **MySQL**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self join:

```
SELECT 
sup.empid AS super_id, 
emp.empid, 
emp.teamid, 
emp.emp_add,
emp.emp_type
FROM your_table emp
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT * 
            FROM your_table  sup
            WHERE emp_type = 'Sup'
            ) sup
ON emp.teamid = sup.teamid

WHERE emp.empid <> sup.empid
```

Comment: Consider expanding on your answer. Why doesn't OP's work? What does your solution do to resolve or bypass that issue?

Answer (score 0):

you have case problem, `'sup'` is needed to be `'Sup'`

also

```
select (select max(emp_id) from table where emp_type = 'Sup') super_id,
    emp_id,
    teamid, emp_add, emp_type
from table
where emp_type != 'Sup';
```

But what you are trying to achieve does not look rationale

Comment: sup vs Sup is only needed in a database or system that is case sensitive. If that collation is not set, uppercase vs lowercase doesn't matter.

Comment: although it is correct, this scenario is valid for this case.

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu please explain why? We have no idea if the columns being described are case sensitive or not. By default MySQL VARCHAR columns, for instance, are not case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you guys. Doing a self join helped me get the right solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
select  a.Super_id,b.emp_id,b.teamid,b.emp_add,b.emp_type
FROM
(SELECT MIN(emp_id) as  Super_id FROM table) a,
(SELECT emp_id,teamid, emp_add, emp_type FROM table WHERE emp_id NOT IN(SELECT MIN(emp_id) emp_id  FROM table)) b
```

Comment: What does this do? Why does this work? Please ***edit*** your answer and explain, thanks.